# Group alternate pairs using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to group a list of [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) which contain alternate family pairs to group them in the following format to minimize duplication.

Here is the DTO structure which I have currently which has duplicate rows as you can see which can be grouped together based on reverse relation also.

```
+----------+------------+-----------+
| PersonId | RelativeId | Relation  |
+----------+------------+-----------+
|        1 |          2 | "Son"     |
|        2 |          1 | "Father"  |
|        1 |          3 | "Mother"  |
|        3 |          1 | "Son"     |
|        2 |          3 | "Husband" |
|        3 |          2 | "Wife"    |
+----------+------------+-----------+
```

into something like this:

```
+----------+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| PersonId | RelativeId | Relation  | ReverseRelation |
+----------+------------+-----------+-----------------+
|        1 |          2 | "Son"     | "Father"        |
|        1 |          3 | "Mother"  | "Son"           |
|        2 |          3 | "Husband" | "Wife"          |
+----------+------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

---

Code which I am trying:

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<RelationDTO> relationDTOList = new List<RelationDTO>
        {
            new RelationDTO { PersonId = 1, RelativeId = 2, Relation = "Son" },
            new RelationDTO { PersonId = 2, RelativeId = 1, Relation = "Father" },

            new RelationDTO { PersonId = 1, RelativeId = 3, Relation = "Mother" },
            new RelationDTO { PersonId = 3, RelativeId = 1, Relation = "Son" },

            new RelationDTO { PersonId = 2, RelativeId = 3, Relation = "Husband" },
            new RelationDTO { PersonId = 3, RelativeId = 2, Relation = "Wife" },
        };

        var grp = relationDTOList.GroupBy(x => new { x.PersonId }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**RelationDTO.cs**

```
public class RelationDTO
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int RelativeId { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
}
```

**Relations.cs**

```
public class Relations
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int RelativeId { get; set; }
    public string Relation { get; set; }
    public string ReverseRelation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is what you need:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<RelationDTO> relationDTOList = new List<RelationDTO>
    {
        new RelationDTO { PersonId = 1, RelativeId = 2, Relation = "Son" },
        new RelationDTO { PersonId = 2, RelativeId = 1, Relation = "Father" },

        new RelationDTO { PersonId = 1, RelativeId = 3, Relation = "Mother" },
        new RelationDTO { PersonId = 3, RelativeId = 1, Relation = "Son" },

        new RelationDTO { PersonId = 2, RelativeId = 3, Relation = "Husband" },
        new RelationDTO { PersonId = 3, RelativeId = 2, Relation = "Wife" },
    };

    var grp = relationDTOList.Join(relationDTOList, 
            dto => dto.PersonId + "-" + dto.RelativeId, 
            dto => dto.RelativeId + "-" + dto.PersonId, 
    (dto1, dto2) => new Relations 
            { 
                PersonId = dto1.PersonId, 
                RelationId = dto1.RelativeId, 
                Relation = dto1.Relation, 
                ReverseRelation = dto2.Relation 
                }).Distinct(new MyEqualityComparer());

    foreach (var g in grp)
        Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", g.PersonId, g.RelationId, g.Relation, g.ReverseRelation);
}

public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Relations>
{
    public bool Equals(Relations x, Relations y)
    {
        return x.PersonId + "-" + x.RelationId == y.PersonId + "-" + y.RelationId || 
        x.PersonId + "-" + x.RelationId == y.RelationId + "-" + y.PersonId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Relations obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the overloaded `equals` method?

Comment: In order to distinct the result list. Because 1-2 should be equal to 2-1, we have to do the equalizer ourselves.

Comment: If you assume that the original list is unique you can get a distinct list by filtering such that personId<RelationId.

Comment: Also please do't stringify just to compare two ints.  It's usually better make two comparisons.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a join operation like

```
var result = relationDTOList
.Where(v => v.PersonId < v.RelativeId)
.Join(
    relationDTOList.Where(v => v.PersonId > v.RelativeId),
    v => new Key{PersonId = v.PersonId, RelativeId = v.RelativeId},
    v => new Key{PersonId = v.RelativeId, RelativeId = v.PersonId},
    (p, q) => new Relations
    {
        PersonId = p.PersonId,
        RelativeId = p.RelativeId,
        Relation = p.Relation,
        ReverseRelation = q.Relation
    }
);
```

The `Key` is:

```
public struct Key
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int RelativeId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I doubt a bit that LINQ is the best choice here as a loop with lookup might be a bit more efficient. However if you really need LINQ, then you could do the following

```
var relations = from person in relationDTOList
    // Match on the exact pair of IDs
    join relative in relationDTOList on
        new { person.PersonId, person.RelativeId } equals
        new { PersonId = relative.RelativeId, RelativeId = relative.PersonId }

    // Build the new structure
    let relation = new Relations {
        PersonId = person.PersonId,
        Relation = person.Relation,
        RelativeId = relative.PersonId,
        ReverseRelation = relative.Relation
    }

    // Order the pairs to find the duplicates
    let ids = new[] {person.PersonId, relative.PersonId}.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray()
    group relation by new { FirstPersonId = ids[0], SecondPersonId = ids[1] }
    into relationGroups

    // Select only the the first of two duplicates
    select relationGroups.First();
```

What this code does is joins the collection with itself on the matching pairs `PersonId`, `RelativeId` and then filters out the second record of each pair thus resulting in a collection where the first person found in the list will be considered as *parent* in the relation.

---

EDIT: The lookup method I was talking about:

```
var result = new List<Relations>();
while (relationDTOList.Any())
{
    var person = relationDTOList.First();
    relationDTOList.RemoveAt(0);

    var relative = relationDTOList.Where(x =>
            x.PersonId == person.RelativeId && x.RelativeId == person.PersonId)
        .Select((x, i) => new {Person = x, Index = i}).FirstOrDefault();

    if (relative != null)
    {
        relationDTOList.RemoveAt(relative.Index);
        result.Add(new Relations {
            PersonId = person.PersonId,
            Relation = person.Relation,
            RelativeId = relative.Person.PersonId,
            ReverseRelation = relative.Person.Relation
        });
    }
}
```

As a note, it empties your original list so you have to make a copy (`list.ToList()`) if you need it further in your code.

Running this code turned out to be about six times faster than the method with `join` I posted before. I also came up with the following grouping method which runs much faster than the *join*, however it's still slower than the *lookup-and-remove* method although they do a very similar thing.

```
var relations = relationDTOList.GroupBy(person =>
        person.PersonId < person.RelativeId
            ? new {FirstPersonId = person.PersonId, SecondPersonId = person.RelativeId}
            : new {FirstPersonId = person.RelativeId, SecondPersonId = person.PersonId})

    .Select(group => new Relations {
        PersonId = group.First().PersonId,
        Relation = group.First().Relation,
        RelativeId = group.First().RelativeId,
        ReverseRelation = group.Last().Relation
    });
```

Comment: Can you also post the loop lookup method you were talking about?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I added the code and some insights I got by running the different versions.

Comment: The groupby version is a nice functional way to do it without emptying the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
var query = relationDTOList.OrderBy(x=>x.PersonId).GroupJoin(relationDTOList,
p => p.PersonId,
a => a.RelativeId,
(p, al) =>
new
{
     p.PersonId,
     p.RelativeId,
     p.Relation,
     Parrent = al.Where(x => x.PersonId == p.RelativeId && x.RelativeId == p.PersonId).SingleOrDefault().Relation
 }
 ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `Groupby` your relations with a sorted `Tuple` of `PersonId` and `RelativeId`, then pick the first item as first relation and the second item as the reverse relation.

**Demo:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Example {

    public static class Program {

        public static void Main (string[] args) {

            List<RelationDTO> relationDTOList = new List<RelationDTO> {
                new RelationDTO { PersonId = 1, RelativeId = 2, Relation = "Son" },
                new RelationDTO { PersonId = 2, RelativeId = 1, Relation = "Father" },

                new RelationDTO { PersonId = 1, RelativeId = 3, Relation = "Mother" },
                new RelationDTO { PersonId = 3, RelativeId = 1, Relation = "Son" },

                new RelationDTO { PersonId = 2, RelativeId = 3, Relation = "Husband" },
                new RelationDTO { PersonId = 3, RelativeId = 2, Relation = "Wife" },
            };

            // Group relations into list of lists
            var groups = relationDTOList
                .GroupBy (r => GetOrderedTuple (r.PersonId, r.RelativeId))
                .Select (grp => grp.ToList ()).ToList ();

            // Output original relations and their reverse relations
            foreach (var group in groups) {
                var relation = group.ElementAt (0);
                var reverseRelation = group.ElementAt (1);
                FormattableString relationOutput = $"PersonId={relation.PersonId} RelativeId={relation.RelativeId} Relation={relation.Relation} ReverseRelation={reverseRelation.Relation}";
                Console.WriteLine (relationOutput);
            }
        }

        private static Tuple<int, int> GetOrderedTuple (int n1, int n2) {
            if (n1 < n2) {
                return Tuple.Create (n1, n2);
            }
            return Tuple.Create (n2, n1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PersonId=1 RelativeId=2 Relation=Son ReverseRelation=Father
PersonId=1 RelativeId=3 Relation=Mother ReverseRelation=Son
PersonId=2 RelativeId=3 Relation=Husband ReverseRelation=Wife
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. But it requires duplicates in the original list.

```
var result = relationDTOList
                .Where(v => v.PersonId < v.RelativeId)
                .GroupJoin(relationDTOList,
                           p => p.PersonId,
                           a => a.RelativeId,
                           (p, al) =>
                                new{
                                    p.PersonId,
                                    p.RelativeId,
                                    p.Relation,
                                    ReverseRelation = al.Where( x => 
                                              x.PersonId == p.RelativeId &&
                                              x.RelativeId == p.PersonId )
                                                .SingleOrDefault()
                                                .Relation} ).ToList();
```